# All Flag Lists in Drupal VBO

Tags: views

I want to diplay all Flag Lists created by any user in the VBO. I am able to get the Flags, however, not the Flag Lists. Could someone guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some details about what you mean by those "Flag lists"? Question I ask myself to understand what you're looking for (I may be completely wrong ...): there is a module named "flag lists", so do you want to create a view of the titles (or description or something) of those lists, and this for each user? Also, VBO is about performing some ACTION ("operation"), while your question is rather related to creating a view (to which you may want to apply some ACTION via VBO afterwards). No?

Comment: Hi Pierre, Yes, it was about the module Flag List. I have, however, solved the issue by creating another content type which suited my requirements. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Merci, but then I suggest you try to add your own answer (just a few lines), and mark that as accepted. So that your question no longer shows up as "unanswered" (there are waaaaayyyyyy too much Qs unanswered on this site ...). Your choice of course ...

Comment: Sure will do that.